# How do I fill a c# observable collection with strings with a callback that was called by an unmanaged DLL?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, callback, unmanaged

My app needs to display strings of data, and those strings come from unmanaged X.dll, which delivers each line through a callback function.

I've created this pipeline to deal with X.dll in c#:

```
Xapp
  -> X-csharp.dll   // c#, managed front end to X-api.dll
     -> X-api.dll   // Shim to expose the pieces of X.dll needed
        -> X.dll    // Original dll
```

I don't want to repeat exactly how it works since that's been done many times, but if I need to say more than **__declspec(dllexport), internal static class NativeMethods, DllImport, etc.,** 
let me know and I'll write it up.

Regarding flow, Xapp does an init call that gets down to X.dll, followed by an open call, and then a getData call that includes a callback declared a lot like this:

```
public delegate void dataCBfunc(IntPtr entry, IntPtr arg);
```

My static callback function includes the conversion

```
string line = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(entry);
```

The whole thing works the way I intended in my testbed app.

Now I'm doing the real MVVM implementation, and I want the lines added to an ObservableCollection that I've bound to a datagrid.  This is where my problem lies.

The callback is static.  I was hoping to do the rudimentary C++ trick of passing an opaque pointer to the instance of the class or to the ObservableCollection, as an "arg" arg to X.dll.  X.dll doesn't need it, it just passes it back to the callback so that the line can be added to the ObservableCollection.  I tried

```
ObservableCollection<RemoteListModel> remoteList 
   = arg as ObservableCollection<RemoteListModel>;
```

and got back

```
Error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Xapp.Model.RemoteListModel>' to 'System.IntPtr' Xapp
```

I've tried a few other things too, and basically get the same type of message, which makes sense.

That said, how might I achieve what I'm after without doing something terrible?  Terrible could mean write it to a file and read it later... less terrible might be using shared memory to do the same... or I could add a couple sockets and do it that way.  I feel like I shouldn't have to resort to such things.  If anyone could help with tips on how to solve this, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're not filling up more than one view model, then why not create a static property for it, so that the static callback can access it?  Or perhaps use some kind of DI container to get the correct instance of the view model at runtime?

Comment: Hi Will... I currently have plans for only one view model and tried making my ObservableCollection static.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong if it should work, I'll revisit.  And a table with an index could work as long as I can access the table, which I'll play with also, thanks.

Comment: I can help you convert that IntPtr back into a managed reference if you first tell me why you think the CLR will not move the observable collection and invalidate the pointer whilst the unmanaged dll is holding it.

Comment: hoodaticus, although a callback is used as the delivery system for the data, the getData() call that kicks it off doesn't return until all the data is delivered.

Comment: Keep in mind that the ObservableCollection is going to be thread-centric, so you'll have to use the UI dispatcher to touch it from your callback.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, a way to access that specific thread, that's why I think Marshaling isn't an option.  If there's a right / better way to do so, that's what I want to learn.  My c# is getting pretty good, but I'm still working on theory of operation, as exemplified here.

Answer (score 0):

My working backup solution, if there's no way to pass a direct instance of the ViewModel (or ObservableCollection) down to the dll and back up to the callback:

1. Name the View user control I added to the MainWindow XAML
2. Create the ViewModel instance in the MainWindow constructor
3. Set the View control DataContext and the MainWindow DataContext to the ViewModel instance
4. Access the ObservableCollection in my static callback with

   TheViewModel rvm = Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as TheViewModel;

As is, I'm restricted to one TheViewModel instance in my app, but if necessary, I could extend it to have the MainWindow DataContext point to a table of instances and use an index in the callback argument to reference the right one.